# XSL trying to get JSON to work

Tags: xml, json, xslt

Trying to get the XML..

```
<user-types>
    <section id="11" handle="user-types">User types</section>
    <entry id="9">
        <name mode="unformatted" handle="home-owner" word-count="2" lang="en" handle-en="home-owner"><![CDATA[Home owner]]></name>
    </entry>
    <entry id="7">
        <name mode="unformatted" handle="contractor-residential" word-count="2" lang="en" handle-en="contractor-residential"><![CDATA[Contractor (residential)]]></name>
    </entry>
    <entry id="8">
        <name mode="unformatted" handle="contractor-non-residential" word-count="2" lang="en" handle-en="contractor-non-residential"><![CDATA[Contractor (non-residential)]]></name>
    </entry>
    <entry id="10">
        <name mode="unformatted" handle="commercial-property-owner" word-count="3" lang="en" handle-en="commercial-property-owner"><![CDATA[Commercial property owner]]></name>
    </entry>
</user-types>
```

To be JSON, but the tag `entry` doent get turned into an array, so JS can only read one of them :(

current broken JSON output

```
{
"user-types" : {
    "section" : {
        "@attributes" : {
            "id" : 11,
            "handle" : "user-types"
        },
        "value" : "User types"
    },
    "entry" : {
        "@attributes" : {
            "id" : 9
        },
        "name" : {
            "@attributes" : {
                "mode" : "unformatted",
                "handle" : "home-owner",
                "word-count" : 2,
                "lang" : "en",
                "handle-en" : "home-owner"
            },
            "value" : "Home owner"
        }
    },
    "entry" : {
        "@attributes" : {
            "id" : 7
        },
        "name" : {
            "@attributes" : {
                "mode" : "unformatted",
                "handle" : "contractor-residential",
                "word-count" : 2,
                "lang" : "en",
                "handle-en" : "contractor-residential"
            },
            "value" : "Contractor (residential)"
        }
    },
    "entry" : {
        "@attributes" : {
            "id" : 8
        },
        "name" : {
            "@attributes" : {
                "mode" : "unformatted",
                "handle" : "contractor-non-residential",
                "word-count" : 2,
                "lang" : "en",
                "handle-en" : "contractor-non-residential"
            },
            "value" : "Contractor (non-residential)"
        }
    },
    "entry" : {
        "@attributes" : {
            "id" : 10
        },
        "name" : {
            "@attributes" : {
                "mode" : "unformatted",
                "handle" : "commercial-property-owner",
                "word-count" : 3,
                "lang" : "en",
                "handle-en" : "commercial-property-owner"
            },
            "value" : "Commercial property owner"
        }
    }
}
}
```

[image]

Using this XSL https://github.com/iwyg/xml-to-json

Comment: You can test results on http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: I don't see a computer program here anywhere. Can you please show the code you are trying to refine that translates XML to JSON?

Comment: Using this XSL https://github.com/iwyg/xml-to-json

Comment: I cannot reproduce your results using the stylesheet you pointed to (the actual output I see is much worse than what you report - http://xsltransform.net/eiQZDbv). I suggest you look for a better source to copy your code from.

Answer (score 0):

Author of the linked script here. 
See https://github.com/iwyg/xml-to-json/issues/1#event-130398157

Answer (score -1):

According to the documentation of xml-to-json this doesn't seem to be intended to be used this way.

Using this document result in an array:

```
<user-types>
    <section id="11" handle="user-types">User types</section>
    <entry>
        <item id="9">
            <name mode="unformatted" handle="home-owner" word-count="2" lang="en"
                  handle-en="home-owner"><![CDATA[Home owner]]></name>
        </item>
        <item id="7">
            <name mode="unformatted" handle="contractor-residential" word-count="2" lang="en"
                  handle-en="contractor-residential"><![CDATA[Contractor (residential)]]></name>
        </item>
        <item id="8">
            <name mode="unformatted" handle="contractor-non-residential" word-count="2" lang="en"
                  handle-en="contractor-non-residential"><![CDATA[Contractor (non-residential)]]></name>
        </item>
        <item id="10">
            <name mode="unformatted" handle="commercial-property-owner" word-count="3" lang="en"
                  handle-en="commercial-property-owner"><![CDATA[Commercial property owner]]></name>
        </item>
    </entry>
</user-types>
```

Does the result look like you wanted it to? Can you modify your XML this way? Otherwise I'm afraid you'll have to make changes to the xml-to-json to be able to handle your kind of xml structure.

Comment: This doesnt work, because this is one of many examples i need to support. i cannot do an automated task like this.

Comment: That's not really a reason to down vote this answer. So are to able to use a custom xslt instead of the one you linked?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be an answer.

Comment: I am hoping to modify `xml-to-json` to meet the needs of this `XML` turning into `JSON`